# The dimension of a projected variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have an algebraic variety $V\subset \mathbb{R}^5$, with dimension 2 and degree d. Consider the projection $V_0=\{x_1,x_2,x_3|x_1,...,x_5 \in V\}$.

While $V_0$ might not be an algebraic variety, it seems intuitive to claim that it is contained in a variety of dimension and degree no larger that $V$'s.

I'm looking for a rigorous proof of this claim. I assume there exists an elementary proof for this.

Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{R}$ a typo for $\mathbb{C}$ (or even better, for $\mathbb{P})$? If not, it might help to answer your question if you will tell us what definition of variety, dimension, and degree you are working with -- I'm not sure of the conventions in this case. Over $\mathbb{C}$ you can see your claim by taking a compactification and using that images of projectives are projective.

Comment: @hunter I'll try to expand, but you'll have to excuse me, I'm lacking some foundations in this field.

Comment: @hunter (sorry for that, problems operating comments here). I am only interested in points with coordinates in $\mathbb{R}$. As I understand, the definitions are taken from the complex case - a variety is the zero set of a polynomial ideal (with real coeffitients, though), the degree is the maximum of the degrees of polynomials in the defining ideal, and the dimension is either of the definitions in here - [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_of_an_algebraic_variety). Could you point me to some reading material about compactification?

Comment: Hi Ariel, the problem with doing algebraic geometry over $\mathbb{R}$ is that there is no Nullstellensatz theorem giving a bijection between affine varieties and ideals. For example, what is the degree of the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$, thought of as the zero locus of the irreducible polynomial $x^2 + y^2$? By compactifications, I just meant projective varieties (so if I give you a polynomial in $n$ variables, you can think of it as giving a variety in $\mathbb{A}^n$, or you can homogenize it w.r.t. another variable to think of it as a variety in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: your wikipedia page is quite wrong, by the way, in the case the field is not algebraically closed -- many of its definitions of dimension are then inequivalent.

Comment: @hunter The wikipedia page was since updated, probably thanks to you. Regarding defining degree and dimension for real-valued curves, I use the definition given here [link](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.0870.pdf) (definition 3.3). For a set S, Take the ideal of all complex polynomials who zero on S, and define the complexification of it as the common zeros of all polynomials in this ideal. The dimension and degree of S are then defined to be the corresponding properties of its complexification.